# Compose Textfield cursor remainsfor a while after navigating to a new screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

After setting up a TextField in the TopAppBar. I encountered two problems:

1. Textfiled gains focused after folding keyboard. When textfield is not triggered, it looks like pic 1. And when I press it(it is focused), the keyboard shows up and tesxfield looks like pic 2. If I fold the keyboard manually, the textfiled keeps pic 2 look. I wish it can turn back to pic 1 look.
   [image: pic 1]
   [image: pic 2]
2. Editting cursor (the pin shape stuff) remains on the screen when I switch to a new screen. pic3 shows the cursor. The color is the same as the background. I'll change it. When I switch to another screen, it remains there like pic 4 shows. It only lasts for a split second and disappears. But it is there.
   [image: pic 3]
   [image: pic 4]

For the first problem, I must missed some parameter I gusess.
I have no idea for the second one. Is it a compose bug?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SearchBar() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(70.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        TextField(
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = null)
            },
            placeholder = {
                Text(
                    "find more...",
                    color = Color.White
                )
            },
            shape = RectangleShape,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                textColor = Color.White,
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Gray,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Black
                ),
            value = text,
            singleLine = true,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding( bottom = 10.dp)
                .size(360.dp,60.dp),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe the first part a bit more, what do you want to happen vs what is happening and what does folding keyboard mean?

Comment: Sure. I've add more details to my question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for the extra details, try this!

For part 1) this code can be added to the TextField to remove focus:

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

TextField(
    ...
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),      
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {     
        keyboardController?.hide()
        focusManager.clearFocus(force = true)
    }),
)
```

Note the Done option will show a little check box in the keyboard you can use to close the keyboard and then this code will remove focus. I'm hoping `onDone` will also be called when manually closing the keyboard.

For part 2) I would reuse the approach. It sounds like a bug, but basically I would try calling `LocalFocusManager.current.clearFocus(force = true)` from where ever you are doing the navigation away from this screen, right before leaving, to force the thing to disappear.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am on `compose bom 2023.10.00-alpha01` and still have your second issue. The previous screen's cursor and keyboard only start disappearing after navigation animation finish, it's feeling very unresponsive.

Currently it's can be solved by disable exit animation of NavHost.

```kotlin
NavHost(
    navController = navController, startDestination = "main",
    enterTransition = { fadeIn() },
    exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None },
    popEnterTransition = { fadeIn() },
    popExitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }
) {
    // ...
}
```